# Use different key for searching instead of value or label in react-select in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-select, searchable

I am using react-select as a searchable drop-down in my react app.
I am referring this link https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select.

In the drop-down options structure, it needs `label` and `value` keys in the respective object in `options`.
My problem is, I dont have any `label` or `value` in my `options` data.
I am having different keys altogether.
I want the drop-down to be searched by different key `tab`.

- My React version : 15.6.2
- react-select version : 1.0.0-rc.10

My code for drop-down:

```
<Select
   name="selectSubTag"
   id="selectSubTag"
   value={this.state.selectedFilter.subTag}
   options={this.state.jobSubTags}
   onChange={this.setSubTag}
   placeholder="Select Sub Tag"/>
```

Where my `options` data looks like below:

```
    this.state.jobSubTags = [
{tab:"tabName 1",tabValue:1},
{tab:"tabName 2",tabValue:2},
{tab:"tabName 3",tabValue:3},
]
```

and now I want the data to be searched by 'tab' key in the dropdown.

Comment: just map your values according to the structure needed

Comment: But that will be an additional iteration over the data I got from server. And I cant change the data structure at server end because its being used at multiple places.

Comment: may be it will need an extra iteration.  You can't change the structure required from an third-party component

Comment: Tried that and it works. Thanks  @Jayabalaji

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `react-select` searches over `value` and `label`, but if you added additional keys it will also include them in the search, so just iterate over the array and append `value` `label` keys equal to the `tab` key or the `tabValue` key and it will search upon them all, but remember that for display, the `react-select` displays the `label` key content

Answer (score 53):

You can use `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` :

```
 <Select
   name="selectSubTag"
   id="selectSubTag"
   value={this.state.selectedFilter.subTag}
   options={this.state.jobSubTags}
   getOptionLabel ={(option)=>option.tab}
   getOptionValue ={(option)=>option.tabValue}
   onChange={this.setSubTag}
   placeholder="Select Sub Tag"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try filterProp="tab" and  matchProp="label" ?