# react-select change name of option fields from ({ value: '', label:''}) to ({ id: '', name:''})

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to change the fields of an option object?

From my BE API i get:

`const items = [{ id: 1, name:'dropdown1'}, { id: 2, name:'dropdown2'}];`

So now i have to remap the fields to `value` and `label`, it would have been nice if i could set those fields dynamically, maybe something like:

```
    <Select
      optionRemapping={{value: 'id', label: 'name'}}
      options={items}
    />
```

**Or maybe i have missed a pattern on how people do this?**

Doing the below feels a bit wrong.

```
items.map((item) => {
  return { value: item.id, label: item.name };
});
```

Comment: Doing this is the way to go if you can't change your API... what'e the problem?

Comment: @keul, Not that i consider it a huge problem, my first thoughts are: waste of operations/performance, more code, spread out code. So i thought that i might have missed a pattern that people use with this lib, maybe doing something with the `component.Option` component, but after further inspection it of the `Option` component i dont see a solution. Now i use a function `remapDropdownItemsForReactSelectLib`, but would be nice to keep all code related to the lib within the lib Select component. I could fork and add this feature, but wanted to see other peoples opinions first.

Comment: @Treycos i dont understand what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized this wasn't a normal select and that you were using the `react-select` library. I suggested an answer mapping your array directly into the select's props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different key for searching instead of value or label in react-select in reactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278189/use-different-key-for-searching-instead-of-value-or-label-in-react-select-in-rea)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` props.

```
<Select
  getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
  getOptionValue={option => option.id}
  options={items}
/>
```

Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/kmoyw8q667

Note: It's generally a good idea to create those functions outside your component to keep the reference stable and avoid unnecessary re-renders of your Select.

Comment: Thanks :) I wonder though if that does 2 `.map` operations behind the scene or if it initialises the option object dynamically with the provided fieldname and use it like `option[userDefinedValueProp]` (from the prop name `getOptionLabel` i dont think it does it like this).

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using the `CreatableSelect` from `react-select`. I have the same issue with the labels, if I use your example for displaying the options it works perfect. If I try to add a new one it doesn't work anymore... If I remove the `getOptionsValue` and `getOptionsLabel` I can add to the `CreatableSelect` custom options. Can you help me please on this matter?

Comment: This is great! The [docs](https://react-select.com/props) are not great tbh.

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve your mapping by doing the following and deconstructing your items :

```
<Select
    options={items.map(({ id, name }) => ({ value: id, label: name}))}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what i am doing now. What i would want is to skip the map operation

Comment: in whatever case an iteration operation will be there. use `options={items}` and the above mentioned accepted answer to map label and value to your custom fields.

Comment: This solution is unnecessary. It adds an extra loop to be done each time this component is rendered.