# React select without label attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there any way to pass data into options in Reac Select component, and list them all if there is no label and value attribute inside?

I am getting data from API and want to pass data and use the name attribute for displaying.

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559410/13405106) may help